# Ethical GPA rounding

Tags: masters, gpa

I am applying for a master's program in the US and am not sure how I should present my GPA ethically when discussing it. I have an undergrad total GPA of 3.394 and when asked to put in my undergrad GPA it only gives room for 2 digits and nothing more. EX: 3.0. Can I round up my GPA since it's so close to 3.4, or would this be unethical and I should round down to 3.3?

To make this as general as possible: How should one round their GPA when only 2 digits are accepted, and they're less than .05 away from the next digit?

Comment: Standard rounding rules would say anything larger than 3.35 should be rounded to 3.4, so 3.394 definitely should.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, I'm guessing that the form doesn't actually *say* to be "rounding" it, we're just inferring that. Arguably they may expect it to be *truncated* instead. (Not that it would be my top guess.)

Comment: _My undergraduate GPA was X.Y5, I wish I had known rounding to X.Z (Z=Y+1) was proper._

Comment: You round up at 1/2 boundaries and down below it.  Just don't round successively, so that 3.498 -> 3.5 -> hey 4.0!  Nor

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are widely accepted standard rounding rules: any number greater than or equal to 3.35 should be rounded up to 3.4.  There is no reason to expect that an application would want non-conventional rules for rounding GPAs.