# Should I round up or down my GPA on a resume?

Tags: cv, gpa

My current cumulative GPA is 3.875. When filling in my information on an online job-site, I can only choose between entering 3.9 or 3.8. In this case, should I round up to 3.9 or round down to 3.8?

Comment: I don't know about your grading system (or your country which you did not disclose) but is there so much of a difference between those two values? 3.9 sounds more.logical to me (don't know if it is better or worse)

Comment: Although rounding down seems safe you are losing a lot of the score. This may not help you during the filtering process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ethical GPA rounding](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91058/ethical-gpa-rounding)

Answer (score 5):

There are no formal requirements on how GPA is calculated and reported in one's CV unless you are filing an application to a particular company that has articulated such rules (which I have not heard of). Such rules usually exist during the admission process to the universities (especially many caveats and intricacies are present for grades conversion in the case of international applications), some academic awards, and other legal matters (for example, immigration procedures).

Thus, the decision is on you. Rounding 3.875 to 3.9 seems to me fairer when the exact rules are not specified. So, in your particular case you need to [round to an available value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_an_available_value), and I suggest using "*Round to the nearest standard value*" without any "ups" and "downs".

Comment: An interesting edge case would be if the rounded grade looks like a perfect score. For example, if 4.0 is the highest grade and you get 3.96, would it be correct to say you got a 4.0? I suppose some may consider it slightly deceptive.

Comment: @GoodDeeds any time something is not reported exactly, some may consider it deceptive. Here, we have a list of available values, and reporting the exact GPA is not an option; thus, some level of deception is inevitable.